# A question about AUTOSAR, does [constr_1221] apply to Initial Value Representation at level 2?

Tags: autosar

When i use a NumericalValueSpecification to init value for an ApplicationPrimitiveDataType of category 'BOOLEAN' with a NonqueuedSenderComSpec, it can correctly generate RTE codes without any compilation error, but as [constr_1221] said, if a DataPrototype is typed by an ApplicationPrimitiveDataType its initValue shall be provided by an ApplicationValueSpecification. So, does [constr_1221] apply to Initial Value Representation at level 2?

Comment: What do you mean: „level 2“? What is this about?

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment, I named it "level2" for [TPS_SWCT_01182] mentioned : 2. It is possible to aggregate an initValue at the level of a ComSpec, namely: NonqueuedSenderComSpec, NonqueuedReceiverComSpec, ParameterProvideComSpec

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any `DataPrototype` that is typed by an `ApplicationDataType` shall only be initialized by means of an `ApplicationValueSpecification`. A `NumericalValueSpecification` or `TextValueSpecification` can be used to initialize a `DataPrototype` typed by an `ImplementationDataType`.

Comment: When I use ValueSpecification in NonqueuedSenderComSpec to initialize the DataPrototype referenced by the arrtibue 'dataElement'，what you said also make sense?